# Shortcode return jumps outside div in wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, shortcode

Problem is that `the_ratigs()` jumps outside `<div id="wpratings">`

```
function wpratings( $atts, $content = null ) {
    return '<div id="wpratings"><b>Rating: </b>' . the_ratings() . '</div>';
}

add_shortcode("wpratings", "wpratings");
```

Shortcode output example:

```
5.00 <<< this is output of the_ratings()
Here is the post content
Rating: <<< this is place of <div id="wpratings">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally, any function that starts with `the_*` is going to **`print`** the result. What you need is an equivalent function `get_the_ratings()`.

In WP, we have `the_title` and `get_the_title`, `the_content` and `get_the_content`. And that's why it fails, shortcodes must `return` values, not `print` them.

You don't mention what plugin is this. If it is [WP-PostRatings](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-postratings/), there's no `get_the_rating`, but you have the following:

```
the_ratings($start_tag = 'div', $custom_id = 0, $display = true)
```

Solution: pass `$display` as `false`.

```
return '<div id="wpratings"><b>Rating: </b>' . the_ratings('div',0,false) . '</div>';
```

Comment: I understand it. get_the_ratings() is undefined function.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do any difference?

```
function wpratings( $atts, $content = null ) {
    $content = the_ratings();
    return '<div id="wpratings"><b>Rating: </b>' . $content . '</div>';
}

add_shortcode("wpratings", "wpratings");
```

`$content` is what is being put between the `[shortcode]content[/shortcode]` tags.