# Why does my shortcode appear outside its parent div?

Tags: wordpress, widget, shortcode

[Putting shortcode on widgets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4D2L3.png)

[#menu-social-media-links is supposed to be inside the .textwidget div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXZoF.png)

Here's my shortcode:

```
add_shortcode( 'social-media', 'social_media_icons' );
function social_media_icons( $atts ) {
    if (has_nav_menu( 'social' )) {
        wp_nav_menu(
            array(
                'container'      => false,
                'theme_location' => 'social',
                'menu_class'     => 'social-links-menu',
                'link_before'    => '<span class="screen-reader-text">',
                'link_after'     => '</span>' . twentynineteen_get_icon_svg( 'link' ),
                'depth'          => 1,
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Can please add your shortcode code here? So expert track issue easily.

Comment: You must be echoing the markup from shortcode you have created, it should be returned instead.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17745647/shortcode-return-jumps-outside-div-in-wordpress

Answer (score 0):

You should return the markup from shortcode, not output it. Here is correct code that will behave as expected.

```
add_shortcode( 'social-media', 'social_media_icons' );
function social_media_icons( $atts ) {
    $markup = '';
    if (has_nav_menu( 'social' )) {
        $markup = wp_nav_menu(
            array(
                'container'      => false,
                'echo'      => false,
                'theme_location' => 'social',
                'menu_class'     => 'social-links-menu',
                'link_before'    => '<span class="screen-reader-text">',
                'link_after'     => '</span>' . twentynineteen_get_icon_svg( 'link' ),
                'depth'          => 1,
            )
        );
    }
    return $markup;
}
```